# Could not convert string to float when importing data python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to import a large dataset using pandas read_csv, but there's a single value that has a character with it, and so it can't be converted to a float.

```
df_chunk = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', dtype={'a': np.float32, 'b': np.float32}, chunksize=1000000, usecols=['a', 'b'])

chunk_list = []
for chunk in df_chunk:
    chunk_list.append(chunk)

df = pd.concat(chunk_list)
```

I get the error message

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '10.24498)'
```

Sure, there's the `)` that disables it from being converted to a float. I'd like to know if there's any way of dealing automatically with this kind of problem.

Comment: Did you try str.replace ? Or regex?; maybe you filter your variable chunk before appending it. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use `converters`

**Ex:**

```
import re
df_chunk = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', converters={"a": lambda x: np.float32(re.sub(r"[^\d.]", "", x)), "b": lambda x: np.float32(re.sub(r"[^\d.]", "", x))},  chunksize=1000000, usecols=['a', 'b'])

chunk_list = []
for chunk in df_chunk:
    chunk_list.append(chunk)

df = pd.concat(chunk_list)
print(df)
```